# Как на странице Update вывести значение поля связной модели,а не ID текущей?

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день.

Начал изучать Yii 1.1.16 и столкнулся с проблемой (для меня).

Есть две таблицы Owner и Namber и связанные поля Owner.numberid и Number.numberid. 
При попытке апдейта записи в базе открывается страница где отображается поле Owner.numberid, а мне нужно отображение Number.number и чтоб при сохранении значение поля сохранялось правильно в таблицу Number.number.
Понимаю, что нужно что-то изменить в методе update в контролере Owner и в форме _form.php, но что и как это сделать?

Вот на пример для вывода поля Type вместо Typeid использовалось следующая конструкция:

В модели таблицы Type

```php
/**
* Returns the list of all category.
* @return list data of all category
*/
public static function All()
{
    $models = Type::model()->findAll(
        array('order' => 'type'));

    $list = CHtml::listData(
        $models,
        'typeid',
        'type',
        'show'
        );

    return $list;
}
```

А в выводе form:

```php
<div class="row">
    <?php 
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'type', 
        Type::All(),
        array('empty' => '(Select a type)')
    );

    echo $form->error($model,'type'); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Но при создании новой записи, строки, или при апдейте, мне в Number не нужен список содержащихся в таблице данных, просто нужно чтоб сохранение происходило в нужную таблицу Number, а не в поле numberid таблицы Owner.

Подскажите как реализовать.

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам не нашел нормального решения. но вот достаточно просто это реализовать так
http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/05/yii.html

по факту в контроллере явно указываешь куда писать

```
   $command->insert('a_analiz_data', array(
                                    'analiz_id' => $max, 
                                    'value' => $val,
                                    'elem_id' => $i,
                                    'user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id,
                                ));
```

Comment: Как вариант, но остается вопрос - когда из грида переходим на страницу редактирования записи, то изначально отображается не сам номер телефона, а его ID в таблице владельца... но в целом да, сохранять должен по идее в нужную таблицу.

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: так укажите ответом